Docker postgres connectivity isuue
Can anyone help me please with this?
what I run:
docker run --name pgres --rm \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=uzer \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234 \
    -e POSTGRES_DB=sample_db \
    -p 5432:5432 postgres:14.1

but I cannot connect to that:

even Nothing happens in the log:
waiting for server to shut down...2024-07-24 18:07:19.272 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
.2024-07-24 18:07:19.273 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2024-07-24 18:07:19.275 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
2024-07-24 18:07:19.275 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
2024-07-24 18:07:19.284 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2024-07-24 18:07:19.396 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2024-07-24 18:07:19.397 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-07-24 18:07:19.397 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-07-24 18:07:19.398 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-07-24 18:07:19.401 UTC [62] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-07-24 18:07:19 UTC
2024-07-24 18:07:19.405 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections






My bad; I had completely forgotten.
Tor was the problem, I turned it off and now the problem is solved.

As you have the database in a container and the pgAdmin in another container, you cannot use "localhost" in the pgAdmin for trying to reach the database as "localhost" will be the container where pgAdmin is running.
Be sure both containers share the same network (Create a network and run both containers within -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#container-networking) and then, on pgAdmin interface instead of "localhost" use the name of the database container, that should fix the problem.
To run the postgres use:
docker run --name pgres --network my-net --rm -e POSTGRES_USER=uzer -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234 -e POSTGRES_DB=sample_db -p 5433:5432 postgres:14.1

To run pgAdmin use:
docker run -p 80:80 --network my-net -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@domain.com' -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret' -d dpage/pgadmin4

Now you will be able to use pgres as server


I tried that but the problem is a step before that I think, based on the error message (connection to the port). --- 2. localhost have always been helpful in my os, so what is the problem now?

even pgAdmin is in another container and it's working with http://localhost:32769/
I tried pgAdmin and intellij Idea to connect,but both failed.

If you run "docker ps" after the container is created, what is the result?

It's normal, 14016e0b2925   postgres:14.1   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   pgres

I didn't notice that the pgAdmin is also running on a docker container, I edited my answer based on this.

using pgres as hostname gives me Unable to connect to server, Connection is bad, Name does not resolve error, and (with the inspiration of your comment, tnx) in another try I could connect with the container's IP, it worked but Why localhost doesn't? while both containers are mapped to the localhost

Try what I just put on my answer, that is working with networks. Localhost is not going to work because pgres is an isolated server and pgadmin is another, therefore if you call to localhost inside pgadmin, it will look for the database in pgadmin server, where there is no db service running. You need then to configure a network and put both containers on it.
